# Over forecasting when using historical data during the pandemic period?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I am new to the forecasting domain. I am dealing with a forecasting task where we had a very high abnormal demand for our products during the pandemic. However, in recent months, the demand trend is continuously decreasing, but since I am using the historical data from two years ago, my trained models keep over forecasting. I am wondering what is the right way to correct this bias? I recall I saw paper by Rob J. Hyndman that addressed such a issue, but I cannot find it any more. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you have only data from the time of the pandemic and no data from non-pandemic times, but you want to make predictions for non-pandemic times? Do you have any further input, e.g. comparison with competitors?

Comment: @frank That is true. No data on comparison with competitors though.